# How to hide the Image inside an ImageView, Without hiding its background?

Tags: android, android-layout, background, imageview, visibility

Well, actually the title says it all.

I need to hide an image from SRC inside an ImageView, Without hiding the whole ImageView with it's background.

The background has to stay.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can select just the src of the view, but you can try wrapping the Image View in a Linear Layout and then set the background of the layout and declare imgView.setVisibilit(View.INVISIBLE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this : imageview src @null.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions

1 : set a transparent image to imageview 
2 : or set the visibility of imageview to Invisible or gone